# How can I open multiple PDF Links in Android WebView in Android?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm building android app where, I placed links to the page in webview on which multiple links are there pointing to PDFs. Everyday, new links are updated. I want to make such functionality that when user clicks on the particular PDF link, it should get opened in default PDF viewer or there itself.

Right now, nothing is happening when user clicks on PDF link within webview.

```
      WebView w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
    WebSettings webSettings=w.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    w.loadUrl("http://collegecirculars.unipune.ac.in/sites/examdocs/_layouts/mobile/view.aspx?List=7ed6607e-6c43-401a-a922-bf8d8bf08ed8&View=dc261157-c533-4a60-977b-506fd87b2a19");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Docs Viewer to read your pdf online:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://collegecirculars.unipune.ac.in/sites/examdocs/Examiantions%20Timetables/Master-In-ARTS(M.A)(Rev.2008)-(24908)_Spl4-8-16.pdf?Mobile=1&Source=%2Fsites%2Fexamdocs%2F_layouts%2Fmobile%2Fview%2Easpx%3FList%3D7ed6607e%252D6c43%252D401a%252Da922%252Dbf8d8bf08ed8%26View%3Ddc261157%252Dc533%252D4a60%252D977b%252D506fd87b2a19%26ViewMode%3DSimple%26CurrentPage%3D1";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

open in browser

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

To override current URL :

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // here you can check PDF
        url = url.toLowerCase();
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

set this MyWebViewClient to your webView.

```
PaymentWebViewClient paymentWebViewClient = new PaymentWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(paymentWebViewClient);
```

Comment: Problem is, the links are updated everyday. Everyday, new updated links are there. Thanks Shabbir but its not working. Kindly open that link then you'll get to know. I tried by that method.

Comment: your webview will be same that you mentioned in the url. When you click internal link of the pdf just load url like this "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf

Comment: Yup! I understood. But I want flow like this:
1. User opens App.
2. Navigate to webview.
3. Clicks on the PDF link.
4. PDF Opens either in Webview or in default PDF Viewer.

Comment: Thanks Shabbir! But what should be in PDF URL? its impossible to add every PDF url since, they update daily. and new pdfs come.

Comment: Is there any way to track the webview url so that we can specify if the url ends with ".pdf" then we can use drive to open.